# How to calculate the resistors to convert 24V to 3.3V using a TCMD4000

Tags: resistors, opto-isolator

I would like to convert a 24V signal to a 3.3V signal using a TCMD4000  optocoupler.
Datasheet: http://www.vishay.com/docs/83513/tcmd1000.pdf

How can I calculate the resistor's value on the input (diode) and output (transistor) to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: This OC may not even be suitable for your application. It has a darlington output stage, which has a relatively high C-E voltage. It may not create a proper 0 when used as open-collector, or proper 1 when used as emitter follower (that's already "harder" to get right). If this all means nothing to you: Feel free to try it, but you're better off getting one with just one single transistor symbol on the output.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the resistor just like you would for driving an LED (actually this is what you are doing) so there is nothing special about it:

**Rv** equals the voltage dropped across it divided by the forward current from the LED.

If you are using the output transistor in an open-collector configuration then you don't need a lot of base current to pull the output on the other side low.

*A one mA LED current will result on the other side as a roughly 10 mA collector current.* This is more than enough to pull a high valued pull-up resistor low, so lets choose this value.

The voltage you would need to drop is about 23V (24V - 1V forward voltage from the LED).

Since we defined the LED current to be as 1mA your **Rv** will be about 23V/1mA = 23kΩ.

On the output transistor you'd just need a single pull-up resistor pulling the output to the desired voltage level. A 10kΩ pull-up resistor seems reasonable.

But after all, do you really need the galvanic insulation? If not you can simply divide the voltage with two resistors

Comment: 50mA is just the limiting normal use value. If this is a digital IO (seems like it) with a collector side pull-up of several kilo-ohms or more and a current transfer ratio in the hundreds, the diode current can be as little as 1mA or maybe less. 1mA -> 1.1V diode Vf -> 22k-ish -> less than 50mW. (with the added benefit of nothing breaking with seriously high spikes!)

Comment: Yeah... I just had a quick glance at the data sheet, corrected my answer :)

Comment: You corrected by removing majority of content. I have a suspicion that was not entirely intended?

Comment: I just have the feeling OP is not entirely settle, so I don't think this is going to be a good solution for him anyway. But I re-added the explanation now for others :P